# input textarea: typing starts in the middle and text does not wrap

Tags: html, css, forms

I have 3 problems with my text area:

1. Any typing starts with the cursor in the middle of the area
2. Its content does not wrap inside the text area
3. The submit button sends it if I hit "enter" - that is not ideal for longer text inputs

Would you please look ash help me with it?

```
<section id="uploads">
    <p>Please enter your text</p>
    <div id="edit-home-text">   
        <form action=""#"" method="POST" name="uploadText">
            <label for="textarea">Insert text</label>
            <input type="textarea" name="textUpload" id="homepageText">
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Insert">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

#list-of-links, 
#uploads,
#list-of-credentials {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #669;
    width: 700px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: It's `<textarea></textarea>`, not `<input type="textarea">`

Comment: And you should probably specify your rows and columns when you do that. Plus, you don't need to specify what the label is for...

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/4SSmr/1/

Comment: SOLUTION: use <Textarea> tag. Solved - many thanks to JoshC and BuddhistBeast for helping me.